# Display ListView TextView based on count acting strange

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView that is being populated with collection of items using a custom adapter.  One of the properties of the collection is a count, and I have two TextViews in my ListView layout, one for the text and one for the count.  I'd like not to display the count TextView if the count is zero.  The code I have works fine when the ListView is initially loaded, but when I scroll the ListView, the count will show on random rows and constantly change if scroll the ListView up and down.  This is the code I have:

```
    public class Main extends ListActivity
    {
         private static CustomAdapter adapter = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {  
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items = GetItems();
            adapter = new CustomAdapter();

            for (Item item : items)
                adapter.addItem(item);

            this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

      /* ADAPTER */
 private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
      {      
    private final List<Item> mData = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        mData.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Item item = (Item)this.getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);

            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.count = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
                 holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

            holder.text.setText(item.getTitle());

            if (item.getCount() > 0)
                 holder.count.setText(item.getCount().ToString());
            else
                holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 


        return(convertView);
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text, count
}
```

Layout:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 

/>
```

EDIT:

I was able to get it working by doing a hacky workaround.  It seems setting the TextView's visibility to Invisible or Gone was causing the issue, so I just changed the color of the items with a zero count to the background color:

```
            if (item.getCount() > 0)
                 holder.count.setText(item.getCount().ToString());
            else
                holder.count.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If anyone has a real fix, please let me know.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the item count conditional statement (if (item.getCount() > 0)) is screwing up the display.  If I take out the condition, the item count's display find, even while scrolling, but it's, obviously, showing 0's, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just do this:

```
if (item.getCount() > 0) {
   holder.count.setText(item.getCount().ToString());
   holder.count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
else
   holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Because you use a ViewHolder, you need to consider the fact that you might get an old `View` that's not showing the `count`. This means we need to make sure that the visibility of `count` is set to `VISIBLE`. Equally we want to hide it if the count is zero - so we change the visibility even though we might get a `View` that is all ready invisible.

Comment: This solved my weird problem as well, can anyone tell me why we get this undefined behavior if we don't explicitly define the visibility of any view that  may have it's visibility defined somewhere else is the logic? Shouldn't the convert view maintain the visibility?

Answer (score 2):

I think you wrong a part of your code, Amend test this code:

```
if (item.getCount() > 0)
    holder.count.setText(item.getCount());
else
    holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: sounds it will cause an `Exception`. (i.e `ResourceNotFoundException`)

Comment: yea, I fixed that as well by adding ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this code you may helpful for the same.

```
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        mListUsers = getUsers();
        lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_user);
        s = new ListAdapter(this, R.id.lv_user, mListUsers);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(s);    
        lvUsers.setClickable(true);

       // lvUsers.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
        {
         Object o = lvUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);
             UserBO obj = (UserBO) o;
             Intent intent = new Intent(Select.this,Update.class);
              intent.putExtra("pid", ""+obj.getId());
              intent.putExtra("name", obj.getName());
              //put data which you want to show and select.

              startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

    public ArrayList<UserBO> getUsers()
    {               

        DBAdapter dbAdapter=DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
        try {
            dbAdapter.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
        }
        dbAdapter.openDataBase();       
        String query="SELECT * FROM profiledatabase";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
        dbAdapter.close();

        ArrayList<UserBO> usersList = new ArrayList<UserBO>();
        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
            UserBO user = new UserBO();
            try {
                user.pid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
                //write code to get data from table

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.i("***" + Select.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            }
            usersList.add(user);
        }
        return usersList;
    }


 // ***ListAdapter***
    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserBO>  {  
 // --CloneChangeRequired
        private ArrayList<UserBO> mList;  
 // --CloneChangeRequired
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<UserBO> list)               { 
 // --CloneChangeRequired
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
            this.mList = list;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View view = convertView;
        try
           {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
                // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
            }
            final UserBO listItem = mList.get(position);
                // --CloneChangeRequired                
            if (listItem != null)
            {
                // setting list_item views                      
                //( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_pid) ).setText( listItem.getId()+"");
                ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name) ).setText( listItem.getName() );
                ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email)).setText(listItem.getEmail());
                ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact) ).setText( listItem.getContact()+"" );

            }}catch(Exception e)
            {
                //Log.i(Select.ListAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());       
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not seeing anything that fixes my issue.